# Magento 2: How to add external image url / CDN url for product images on category and product details pages?

Tags: magento2, product-images, cdn

I am using Magento 2.3.3. I need help to add CDN url only for product's images on category and product details pages.

NOTE: Except product images, no images will come from CDN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try ImageEngine with this guide: https://imageengine.io/docs/integration-guides/imageengine-magento2
There is also a plugin available in the marketplace. Just search for "ImageEngine".

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the config setting `web/secure/base_media_url` to achieve this; it will cause any URL generated by Magento that contains the media directory to use the provided URL.